# Would a Triumph Thruxton be suitable for everyday use?

Tags: maintenance, motorcycle, wear

I really love the look and design of the Thruxton and am considering getting one. I use my current motorbike every day, from getting to work and back, to shopping, to long trips. Its a bullet proof little Honda that's never given me any issues.

I was wondering if a Thruxton could put up with the constant use (maybe average of 20klms of travel per day in heavy traffic). Has anyone used one of these as a daily rider? If so was it ok to use? What issues did you encounter? Would you recommend the bike for this kind of use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Thruxton is gorgeous, it's a pure joy to ride and will put a huge smile on your face. A few things to keep in mind however, it's designed to be a cafe racer, look at how aggressive that riding position is. I'm not sure about Australia, but in the states, replacement parts for British bikes are much harder to come by than Honda parts.

Comment: +1 I may get struck down for saying this, but most all modern, fuel injected motorcycles are fairly low maintenance. I agree with @hillsons that a bigger concern may be the suitability of the type of bike (cafe racer) than the make/model of the bike. As a daily rider and for going to the store, I'd personally consider a bike where storage isn't an afterthought--something with good hard cases.